# What happens if a file listed for backup with rsync is in use?

Tags: rsync

I have a cron job to `rsync` certain files from my home folder every hour.

Would anything bad happen if a file scheduled to be backed up is being edited at the time of backup?

Right now, I am avoiding that chance by using another cron job to run two minutes *before* the backup one to remind me to save open stuff.

(I looked through "Questions that may already have your answer" and "Similar Questions" before posting but I'm not seeing a duplicate hence the question.)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu files that are opened by any program aren't handled any special but are accessible like any other file. You even can delete them (but that will only delete the file name entry, the file's data will still be there until the file is closed).

But depending on the program that is using the file the file's content may be invalid or out of sync with other file's content. So for a backup it is usually a good idea to make sure that all files are closed unless to know that this isn't a problem. Otherwise restoring your backup may get you an unusable or faulty system.